# Relationship between the Navagrahas and the AshtaDikpalakas

Tags: navagraha

Each of the 8 directions is associated with a presiding deity (East -- Surya, etc). Similarly, when we look at the Navagrahas, they are arranged in a particular way (what is the actual arrangement?) I believe with the Surya at the center, not in the East. In what way are these two arrangements related?